# 4 monitor computer, resets task bar every time I turn off screens, method to move task bar and resize not using mouse?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, displayport

I have a computer with 4 screens.

4 monitor display:

[image: 4 monitor display]

Monitor 1 (primary) is 2k 165hz displayport screen that I use for gaming, 2 & 3 are 1080p @60 for other stuff, and 4 is a drawing tablet.

My task bar normally sits on the right hand screen (3), 4 lines thick.  My issue is that when I turn off the screens for the night, the next morning, after everything is turned back on, the task bar has moved back to the center screen.

I know display port has its own thing that disconnects and reconnects, but I have been dealing with this for years and was finally the straw that broke the camels back this morning.  The fact it is the primary screen so games appear on it cannot be changed.  Locking the task bar does not change the behavior.

Other fixes I would be ok to use, would be any commands that can move the task bar and resize it without using mouse, etc, because I use VoiceAttack, a program that lets you use voice commands, and could automate it too, just this is annoying, and I am sure I am not the only one that has to deal with something like this.

Comment: try using AutoIt as a bandaid solution .

Comment: compare the content of the Windows registry between the two taskbar locations ... write a script to do the change